# How to fit a linear mixed effects model to my data using lme4 in R?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

My data consists of 790 columns of normalized metabolite expression values (some collected at a first and second-time point) for approximately 100 subjects ( so 200 gene expression values corresponding to 790 different metabolites altogether).

I am trying to fit a linear mixed effect model to my data, and I am having some medication kept as fixed effects which are known to influence the metabolite levels (BB, WA, ACOG), and also age and adiposity.

My predictor here will be my disease status, and the response will be metabolite levels. Here is the formula I have tried so far ( although I am coming up against some error messages), therefore I don't think I have my response variable in the correct format. Please could anybody suggest a correct format?

```
        fit <- lmer (data1[, 1:790] ~ data1$Diseasestatus + 
         + data1$BB + data1$WA + data1$ACOG + data1$Age + data1$Adiposity ,REML = F)
```

Error messages include;

```
  Error in model.frame.default(drop.unused.levels = TRUE, formula = data1[, 1:790] ~  : 
     invalid type (list) for variable 'data1'
```

Just using one particular metabolite as the response i.e data1[, 1] got the error message of

```
  Error in KhatriRao(sm, t(mm)) : (p <- ncol(X)) == ncol(Y) is not TRUE
```

I am sorry if this is a naive question. No examples I have found thus far actually show the format of the response variable data. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank-you

Edit; I aim to compare the 790 metabolites between the control and inflammatory bowel disease groups ( through looking at the effect size and also p values).  I have found some code that I have changed slightly, but I am still not able to do see any output ( once I have converted the data into the correct format). I ultimately would like a table with one column metabolites, one column effect size values and one column p values.  I am not getting this unfortunately;

```
   fit1 <- lmer(expr_val ~ Diseasestatus + BB + WA + ACOG + Age + Adiposity + 
  (1|participantID), data = data_long)

   compare <- lmer(expr_val ~ BB + WA + ACOG + Age + Adiposity + 
                   (1|participantID), data = data_long)


   test<-anova(fit, compare)
   out<-summary(fit)$coef
   res <- c(out[2,1],out[2,2],a$"Pr(>Chisq)[2],summary(fit1)$devcomp$dims[1])
```

I have included some data too (for the first 20 participants (ID I have changed) and the first 10 metabolites, in case this helps. 0 for medication columns means the participant is not taking the drug, 1 they are taking it. Similarly for disease status 0 is control, 1 is disease. BMI values are used here too rather than adiposity measurements.

dput(data) =

```
 structure(list(Participant_ID = c(34L, 35L, 119L, 157L, 158L, 
 208L, 209L, 1364L, 1365L, 127911L, 127912L, 154110L, 154120L, 
 167113L, 167123L, 171713L, 171724L, 184212L, 184213L), BB = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
 0L, 1L), ACOG = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), WA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BMI = c(23.94688606, 
 25.87052536, 26.38413048, 24.10971069, 27.77280045, 24.93728065, 
 26.8804493, 23.90113258, 25.07429123, 27.60118484, 23.12600708, 
 26.39195442, 23.01516533, 31.3666172, 31.80447578, 24.03654861, 
 25.11828613, 24.17065239, 28.48728561), Age = c(76L, 76L, 68L, 
 68L, 68L, 57L, 57L, 56L, 56L, 60L, 60L, 44L, 44L, 58L, 58L, 71L, 
 71L, 56L, 56L), Diseasestatus = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Met1 = c(0.326537646, 
 0.362137501, 0.403331692, 0.343789581, 0.437786804, 0.720648545, 
 0.974583105, 0.565800103, 0.613001417, 0.547743467, 0.337683125, 
 0.393250468, 0.465795971, 0.390206584, 0.172261362, 0.382496277, 
 0.435237338, 0.945312001, 0.321214419), Met2 = c(0.465736593, 
 0.540715637, 0.472693123, 0.681156674, 0.416291697, 0.487306504, 
 0.499092007, 0.634904337, 0.408109505, 0.808546214, 0.4113336, 
 0.924069141, 0.673204104, 0.693500596, 0.522794352, 0.373602067, 
 0.716407827, 0.649634492, 0.514429127), Met3 = c(0.902854296, 
 0.413241218, 0.418436978, 0.599698582, 0.806269489, 0.746859677, 
 0.461750237, 0.534943022, 0.511101841, 0.339406025, 0.235624644, 
 0.405761674, 0.312947287, 0.409833325, 0.026137354, 0.477175654, 
 0.387610389, 0.226427797, 0.19742037), Met4 = c(0.99425024, 0.923934731, 
 0.804677487, 0.31081605, 0.351561982, 0.529615606, 0.756342125, 
 0.968115646, 0.989016517, 0.938703504, 0.841777433, 0.103150219, 
 0.68397041, 0.903129097, 0.897388285, 0.905293975, 0.992337012, 
 0.358619626, 0.159601445), Met5 = c(0.527268407, 0.646332723, 
 0.646042578, 0.163344212, 0.202267074, 0.536976636, 0.789061409, 
 0.725657854, 0.697350164, 0.044081822, 0.959496477, 0.295039796, 
 0.120109301, 0.160817478, 0.901107461, 0.529179518, 0.573373775, 
 0.560701172, 0.325806613), Met6 = c(0.809497068, 0.614253411, 
 0.375421856, 0.446069992, 0.710859888, 0.474587655, 0.217817798, 
 0.464787031, 0.5540375, 0.62822217, 0.082906217, 0.294754096, 
 0.862216149, 0.427856328, 0.418944666, 0.516181576, 0.544516281, 
 0.519113772, 0.279522811), Met7 = c(0.419627992, 0.365954584, 
 0.434398151, 0.313441811, 0.368051981, 0.660614914, 0.825809828, 
 0.412109302, 0.545740249, 0.326247449, 0.373035298, 0.380623499, 
 0.428859232, 0.321044089, 0.24939936, 0.298372835, 0.387467105, 
 0.906034877, 0.147250125), Met8 = c(0.549683979, 0.347795497, 
 0.465729386, 0.625045713, 0.551784129, 0.348174756, 0.4334509, 
 0.594903245, 0.561353241, 0.621274979, 0.231389704, 0.308801446, 
 0.464799907, 0.401663011, 0.332966555, 0.109698561, 0.184359915, 
 0.091447702, 0.20568595), Met9 = c(0.605266628, 0.316564583, 
 0.166558136, 0.337470002, 0.458328756, 0.409329111, 0.269424154, 
 0.514746553, 0.408357879, 0.572246814, 0.264718681, 0.125162297, 
 0.211230627, 0.655667116, 0.034006203, 0.189685846, 0.243832622, 
 0.360657636, 0.259174139), Met10 = c(0.576174353, 0.214361265, 
 0.523133504, 0.549085457, 0.430400583, 0.53943429, 0.441563681, 
 0.401805576, 0.386025835, 0.514017513, 0, 0.330305736, 0.567380079, 
 0.50505895, 0.242814909, 0.306522744, 0.132950297, 0.207312191, 
 0.328760686)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have one row per measurement per individual. So, if for each of 100 individuals you took 790 measurements twice, you should have a dataset that is 100*790*2 rows long. Your columns should be the participant ID, the metabolite type, and your other variables. Because each participant is measured multiple times, participant-level characteristics like age will be duplicated across rows (i.e., you will have multiple rows with the same age because they all correspond to the same individual).

To get the data in this format, you'll need to turn your dataset from wide to long. There are a variety of tools in R to do that, but I think the `melt()` function in the `data.table` package is fairly easy to use. Your code will look something like the following, assuming the only variables in your dataset are the 790 metabolite columns, participant ID, and the variables you've included in the model:

```
data_long <- melt(data, measure.vars = 1:790, variable.name = "met_type",
                  value.name = "expr_val")
```

This long dataset (which I've called `data_long`) should have a different structure from your current dataset. Rather than a column for each type of metabolite, there will be one column for the metabolite expression value (`expr_val`) and another for the type of metabolite (`met_type`). You should also have a column, which I've called `participantID` in the model, that identifies each participant (which you probably already have).

From here, how you specify the model will depend on your theories about the 790 metabolites. If each type of metabolite is important, you can add metabolite as a fixed, measurement-level covariate, which will be split into 789 dummy variables. If the specific type of the 790 metabolites is not important to your theory but needs to be accounted for, you can add a random effect for metabolite, which gives your model two random effects (one for participant and one for metabolite type). The model, with two random effects, should look like the following:

```
fit <- lmerTest::lmer(expr_val ~ Diseasestatus + BB + WA + ACOG + Age + Adiposity + 
                       (1|participantID) + (1|met_type), data = data_long)
```

If you run `summary()` on the `fit` object, you will get the coefficient estimates and estimates of the variance components. If you want to get p-values to test whether the coefficient of `Diseasestatus` differs from zero, you need to use the `lmerTest` package.  The coefficient on `Diseasestatus` represents the difference between the average metabolite expression value for those with the disease and that for those without.

---

**EDIT**:

It looks like you want an estimate of the effect for each metabolite. It makes sense to run a separate model for each metabolite, though after doing so you should correct for multiple comparisons. You need to loop through each metabolite and fit a separate model to each one. You could do this with either the long or the wide dataset. We'll stick with the wide dataset since it's smaller.

```
fit_list <- setNames(lapply(paste0("Met", 1:790), function(i) {
    fit <- lmer(data_wide[[i]] ~ Diseasestatus + BB + WA + ACOG + 
                   Age + Adiposity + (1|participantID), 
                data = data_wide)
    summary(fit)$coef["Diseasestatus", c("Estimate", "Pr(>|t|)")]
}), paste0("Met", 1:790))

dplyr::bind_rows(fit_list, .id = "Metabolite")
```

To run this model you must have the `lmerTest` package loaded. You didn't see any p-values previously because you didn't have it loaded before running the model. The p-values from these tests use the Satterthwaite degrees of freedom.

Comment: Thank-you for this. I have re-edited my question slightly. I aim to ultimately compare the 790 metabolites between the control vs IBD, and am trying to work on some correct code to get an output which shows the effect size and p values for each metabolite, but struggling to do this at the moment. Please let me know if you have any suggestions, if I am able to solve it in the meantime, I will update. Thanks again!

Comment: I edited my answer. You need to loop through each metabolite and perform a test for each one.

Comment: Thank you for editing your answer. I am currently coming up with an error which is as follows;                                                                                                                  
Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations
Called from: checkNlevels(reTrms$flist, n = n, control). Please could you tell me if there is any way to overcome this?

Comment: After seeing the preview of the dataset you posted, I made another edit. See if this works.

Comment: Thanks again for replying. The error message this time was            
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"
dplyr"                                                                                                                                          I am using your code above and apart from when specifying the .id="Metabolite", there are no other ". I will update if I can get rid of this message.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. Try again. At this point this is a program debugging problem that is kind of beyond the scope of CV. I can't really help you without the actual dataset.

Comment: Thanks for trying anyhow. Sorry , the full error was Error: unexpected symbol in:
"}), paste0("Met", 24:813)
dplyr"                                                                                                                                      I will try and see where the problem lies and update here once I get the output. Thanks again